# How to update project minus one file in subclipse

Tags: subclipse

Is there an easy way to use subclipse (svn) to update an entire project, but exclude one file from the update? I need this because there is one file which has computer-specific constants (mostly paths).

Comment: Does svn:ignore solve your problem? [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this file checked in in some changeset?  If so, you can update your project then 'revert' it back to that existing revision with 'Team => Update to Version'.  Tedious but until this file syncs up with the head...

Comment: The file is one which is downloaded from svn but needs to be changed for every computer. I'd like for a certain user's version to stay in the repository so they don't become too annoyed when they are told to update and all of their paths are reset.

Comment: How about eliminating the file and make it something that's generated for the computer if it's not found?